# Access - Creating a query to match multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

What I am trying to do is compare different snapshots of data, to calculate changes over time. It's a report on computers. I want to find if one combination in a table matches the same combination in another table. For example:

```
April_Table               May_Table
Computer      User        Computer      User
192.168.1.1   Jim         192.168.1.1   John
192.168.1.2   Jerry       192.168.1.2   Jerry
```

So, the query would return 192.168.1.2 Jerry.

I've done this with one combination before, but I've never done it with two before. I haven't found a way to do this with two.

I'm expecting to find 192.168.1.2 Jerry.

Comment: Perhaps just do a compound join in query? You have a table for each month? That would not be optimum normalization.

Comment: Reports are generated daily. I don't save all the tables, but if I need to do comparisons between dates, I use 2 tables to do that. Mostly because they're in different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an INNER JOIN:

```
select a.*
from April_Table as a inner join May_Table as m
on m.Computer = a.Computer and m.User = a.User
```

or with EXISTS:

```
select a.*
from April_Table as a
where exists (
  select 1 from May_Table as m
  where m.Computer = a.Computer and m.User = a.User
)
```